# Any meteor router supporting url fragments ? i.e. window.location.hash?

Tags: meteor, url-routing, iron-router

I recently used iron router for meteor, I have been surprised to see that browsing from one page to another using the router will actually reload the whole page content. This is due to the fact the url path to be changed while browsing from one page to another. It might be useful for websites browsable by search engines but building a web application this is not what I'm looking for.

Actually I was expecting something based on fragments where changing the fragment would for example put it in the session so that I might be using it directly in my template. The following code should produce the wanted effect (jQuery):

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function() {
  Session.set('hash', window.location.hash);
});
```

But before to use my own solution I would like to ensure I'm not reinventing the wheel. Is there any meteor router or any other framework supporting page rendering based on fragments (in opposition to the path) ?

Comment: This is weird, IronRouter uses HTML5 history push states to provide exactly what you need. Check this iron-router demo https://iron-router-progress.meteor.com for example, it should behave as you expect in modern browsers.

Comment: I agree with @saimeunt that iron-router should work for your purpose -- I definitely don't see a page reload when changing routes in my app. Do you perhaps have all your routes to be server-side for some reason? Alternatively you could use page.js (http://visionmedia.github.io/page.js/) for which there is already a meteor package as well (https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/page-js).

Comment: @saimeunt ok I got it, I was manually browsing from one page to another directly changing the browser address. I just realised that using the actual links <href="/aPage">Test</a> worked the way I expected.

Comment: Personally i think the currently available routers are a bit weird in the way they handle reactivity. To me, a truly reactive router would just help you map the path reactively to a user-defined set of reactive variables, like the ones in `Session` or `ReactiveDict`, that you can then use in your other logic, thus preserving the reactive flow. Glad to see i'm not the only person thinking this way. I'm working on a router package that works this way, but it's not public yet.
Btw, meteor has the renderDynamic call, which was made for exactly this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iron-router does not actually reloads the whole page as long as we are doing this through tags `<a href="/somePage">ClickMe</a>` or via the Router function `Router.go('/somePage');`
Manually introducing the url in the browser's field would however reload the whole page (which would not be the case using a fragment)

For those looking for dynamically putting the fragment into the session here is the full code I used:

```
function storeHashInSession()
{
  Session.set('hash', window.location.hash);
}

Meteor.startup(function()
{
    storeHashInSession();
});

$(window).on('hashchange', function()
{
    storeHashInSession();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on what browser you are using.  I haven't looked at iron-router in a while but as of [version 0.6.0](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/master/History.md#v060) non-IE browsers used HTML5 history push state while IE<10 made fresh page requests from the server each time.

See this issue for details:  https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/issues/14

For our startup we are still using [`mini-pages`](https://github.com/cmather/meteor-mini-pages).

If `iron-router` doesn't already support push state in IE<10, hopefully it will soon.